# Наследуемость и вложенность CSS

Tags: css

не могу понять для  чего нужно указывать всю структуру до нужного тебе класса, ведь если прописать только один класс стили все равно сработают

К примеру

```
<section class='1'>
  <div class='2'>
   <div class='3'></div>
  </div>
 </section>
```

И если мне нужно применить стиль только к '3' я ведь так и могу написать '.3{...}', а не указывать '1' и '2' перед этим

Comment: Не указывайте, никто и не заставляет

Comment: _ведь если прописать только один класс стили все равно сработают_ - все зависит от стилей, может сработать, а может и нет

Comment: Можешь. Но если у тебя, например, ещё один див где-нибудь будет с таким же классом, а тебе нужно именно вот этот немного скорректировать, то, если ты просто укажешь класс, изменятся все, а если укажешь `.1 > .2 > .3`, то можно изменить только этот. Более точное указание.

Answer (score 0):

CSS-правила имеют свой вес, который определяется как раз количеством и качеством указанных Вами селекторов.
Для конкретного элемента может быть указано несколько правил, и будет применено правило с бОльшим весом.